# Is the strings command equivalent to cat on non-binary file?

Tags: cat, binary

This is potentially a stupid question, or simply the answer might not be helpful—but I am curious.  It looks like the `strings` command and the `cat` command are equivalent on non-binary files.  Is this true?  Or are there some caveats of using `strings` on all file-types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `strings` finds strings of at least four printable characters. Try `echo abc | strings`. I am sure there are more subtle differences. So, the answer to the question in the title is "no".

In addition, the two commands have different purposes and a range of different command line options, which makes them very non-equivalent.

Comment: See also `echo Stéphane | strings` which gives `phane` with GNU `strings` (`St` too short, `é`  not considered as text).

Answer (score 2):

Of course they're not equivalent. Here's an example with normal text files

```
$ cat file_with_newline_at_the_end
with new line



another line


$ strings file_with_newline_at_the_end
with new line
another line
$ cat file_without_newline_at_the_end
```

As you can see, `strings` just ignore blank lines but cat simply passes the whole byte stream to the terminal by default. That also means `cat` knows nothing and doesn't care about file encodings but `strings` does. By default `strings` just looks for 7-bit ASCII characters so strings with a byte larger than 0x7F will produce different output. UTF-16 and UTF-32 files also won't work with `cat` but outputs correctly in GNU `strings` with the `--encoding` option

Besides `strings` looks for *printable characters* (0x20-0x7E) so files with control characters like a vertical tab (0x0B) will have different outputs

```
$ echo -e "abcd\x0bcdef" | strings
abcd
cdef
$ echo -e "abcd\x0bcdef" | cat
abcd
    cdef
```

There are also many options that produce different output such as `-o` or `-t` in `strings` or `-benstv` in `cat`

Another difference is that `strings` looks for strings at least 4 characters long by default, as mentioned in the other answer

GNU `strings`:

> For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given with the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.

macOS `strings`:

> Strings looks for ASCII strings in a binary file or standard input. Strings is useful for identifying random object files and many other things. A string is any sequence of 4 (the default) or more printing characters [ending at, but not including, any other character or EOF]. Unless the - flag is given, strings looks in all sections of the object files except the (`__TEXT`,`__text`) section.  If no files are specified standard input is read

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about new lines!

Comment: not only new lines but also non-printable characters