# Why can't I use the strings command on the strings binary?

Tags: cat, binary

I cannot run the `strings` command on the `strings` binary (which is for me located at `/usr/bin/strings`:

```bsh
$ strings $(which strings)
strings
```

I also can't copy it and try it on the copy of it:

```bsh
$ cp -L $(which strings) /tmp/
$ strings /tmp/strings
strings
```

The only way I can get it is to capture the output in `cat`:

```bsh
$ strings <<< $(cat $(which strings))
...
```

But there are other commands that this kind of self-referencing works with (e.g., `cat $(which cat)`).  I looked it up and [it works on some other machines](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/3-s2.0-B9780128054727000085-f08-04-9780128054727.jpg) [image pulled from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/string-utility)].  Perhaps it is a macOS thing?  (I am currently running macOS 10.14).

I understand that this is a silly question with potentially no use case, but I am just curious...

Comment: Use `strings $(type -p strings)`.

Comment: I wonder what's the output of `which strings` on your system? On mine (Ubuntu 16), `strings $(which strings)` outputs the expected gibberish.

Comment: @waltinator On my machine, `strings $(type -p strings)` and `strings $(command -v strings)` give the same output as `strings $(which strings)`.

Comment: @berndbausch `/usr/bin/strings`.  It's not a symlink or anything either.  File permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x`.  Edit: in your answer to my [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646325/), `echo abc | strings` doesn't work for me either; I have to run `strings <<< $(echo abc)`.

Comment: I am surprised but I have neither MacOS nor BSD to check. I don't know if your shell interprets `$(...)` differently than Bash?

Comment: @berndbausch Hmm, I am using Bash too: `GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same behavior in both zsh and bash in macOS. It turns out `strings` in macOS just looks in the **non-text sections** of the Mach-O binary. From `man strings`:

> Unless the `-` flag is given, strings looks in all sections of the object files except the (`__TEXT`,`__text`) section.  If no files are specified standard input is read.

So to force `strings` to treat the file as pure binary instead of Mach executable you need to pass the `-` flag. `strings - "$(command -v strings)"` will work as expected as long as you've not redefined `string` as a function.

In `zsh`, you can just use `strings - =strings` where `=strings` expands to the path of the `strings` command regardless of whether you've also got a function by that name or not (see also `"$(command -ve strings)"` in the `yash` shell).